# How to know if $anchorScroll will produce a window scroll?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to know if *window.onscroll* will call after *$anchorScroll();*

Now, I'm making this.

```
 // if this is true, I'm sure that window.onscroll will be trigger
 if(angular.element('#' + $location.hash())[0].getBoundingClientRect().top !== 0){
      $anchorScroll();
 }
```

But I want to know if there are some other method prettiest to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just add a listener to `window.onscroll`, call `$anchorScroll` and see if your handler fires? It's unclear why you need to know if a scroll actually happens or not. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need execute a function until the user make an action
And the automatic scroll made by the browser generate problems ( when the url has a hash)